# Simple pathfinding

Tags: javascript, breadth-first-search, path-finding, a-star, 2d-games

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html) awesome introduction into A* pathfinding algorithm. However, for some reason, my JS implementation of [BFS algorithm](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html#breadth-first-search) tends to 90 degrees paths: https://codepen.io/stee1rat/pen/GyeyzB?editors=0010, even though examples in the article behave differently. Maybe there should be some condition for popping/shifting out `next` node from `frontier` array? I can't figure out how to make it behave the same way as the python examples do.

Comment: That looks like the shortest path to me.  What were you expecting?  (how do the python examples behave?)  (Maybe you need a refresher in Manhattan distance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)

Comment: @Wyck it is the shortest. However, if you would look in the article's example, most of the paths are diagonal, not 90 degrees. It would be the same length, but looks more natural.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is perfectly fine. The difference between your solution and the other one is how you break ties in the open list, i.e. if you have 4 nodes with the same cost, which one is the next one you are going to expand. A* is selecting one and your algorithm selects another. Changing your selection to choose the next node to explore differently should suffice to give you a different shortest path solution.

This happens often in game maps, look at this example:

```
S _ _ _
_ _ _ _
_ _ _ _
_ _ _ G
```

let us only consider vertical and horizontal movements, having all movements the same cost, there are many shortest path solutions:

```
S 1 2 3
_ _ _ 4
_ _ _ 5
_ _ _ G

S _ _ _
1 _ _ _
2 _ _ _
3 4 5 G

S _ _ _
1 2 3 _
_ _ 4 _
_ _ 5 G

...
```

If you want to deepen your knowledge about breaking ties in the frontier (for bidirectional A*), have a look to this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/290447195_An_analysis_of_bidirectional_heuristic_search_in_game_maps).

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. However, turned out what I was looking for was [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance): https://codepen.io/stee1rat/pen/GyeyzB?editors=0010